# Is it possible to find analytic form of a circolar function if i know 3 points of that?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, interpolation

Easy question: if i have 3 points and i suppose my function trigonometric can i find the analytic form of this one? If no, why?

Edit: and what if i know the period and the max and min?

Comment: What set of functions do you consider trigonometric?

Comment: sin fx, cos fx, and composition of those.

Comment: What kind of compositions?

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_interpolation might help you.

Comment: @mvw  That's painful...

Comment: Painful? How do expect to learn anything with that attitude?

Comment: @mathreadler im still trying, dont worry :)

Answer (score 1):

There will be no unique reconstruction, here is a counter example:

[image]

Comment: But if i know the period? This will be unique!